# Java 8 JPA Repository Stream row-by-row in Postgresql

Tags: spring, postgresql, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Reading [this](http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html) about MySQL defines certain query hints (`@QueryHints` annotation) that are **required** in order to make MySQL process the result set row-by-row.  Does anyone know for sure what (if anything) is required for PostgreSQL?

Here is the reference query definition in the repository for MySQL:

```
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE))
@Query(value = "select t from Todo t")
Stream<Todo> streamAll();
```

Comment: PostgreSQL need similar settings (namely `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` & a specific fetch-size). However, you can control fetch-size as you like (f.ex. [the JDBC docs contains an example with `st.setFetchSize(50)`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor)). There is also another limitation: only a single query can be run in this "scrollable" mode.

Comment: I did see that example in the docs with the 50.  The code above uses Integer.MIN_VALUE, didn't know what postgresql would do with that, hence my question.   Separately, can you explain the limitation a bit more?  Is that across all connections?  I am assuming other queries can run in parallel though?

Comment: no, PostgreSQL's JDBC driver allows multiple queries in a single statement. (f.ex. `"INSERT INTO ...; SELECT ...;"`): that's not allowed in scrollable mode (and usually not portable anyway). -- Don't use a negative value for fetch-size in PostgreSQL. Use `@QueryHint(name=HINT_FETCH_SIZE,value="1")` for row-by-row read, *>1* for batch-by-batch read (with some caching) and `"0"` to turn off scrollability.

Comment: For contrast [`setFetchSize(rows)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)) should throw `SQLException` when *the condition `rows >= 0` is not satisfied* (that is not honored by MySQL's JDBC driver).

Comment: @pozs, I think your last comment is what I am looking for as an answer, maybe submit that?  Would like to know any performance differences with Java streams and fetch_size=1 vs fetch_size=25 though.  That is, should it always be 1?

Comment: this depends on how many rows are you expecting & how wide are your rows. So I advise you to test multiple variants. But I predict that fetch-size=1 won't be the fastest, and above some value, it will became slower and slower again (if you reach the number of your rowcount f.ex. then it actually won't scroll anything)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Its PostgreSQL equivalent is:

```
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "1")
```

For contrast [`setFetchSize(rows)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)) should throw `SQLException` when *the condition `rows >= 0` is not satisfied*. This is not honored by MySQL's JDBC driver.

Though in PostgreSQL you can actually set up values greater than `1` to allow some caching by PostgreSQL's JDBC driver. The [docs' example](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor) of `50` seems reasonable (unless you have irrationally wide rows). You could also choose this value to be a portion of the expected row count. Test a few variants before deploying your application.