# Stream rows from PostgreSQL (with fetch size)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-boot-jpa

I would like to stream results from PostgreSQL 11.2 and not read all results to memory at once. I use the newest stable SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE.

I read the article how to do it in MySQL. 
http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html
I also read article how to do it in PostgreSQL:
[Java 8 JPA Repository Stream row-by-row in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256311/java-8-jpa-repository-stream-row-by-row-in-postgresql/43257947)

I have repository like that:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, UUID> {
    @Query("SELECT p from Product p")
    @QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "50"))
    Stream<Product> streamAll();
}
```

Than I use the stream that way:

```
  productRepository.streamAll().forEach(product -> export(product));
```

To make the example easier, 'export' method is completely empty.

When I call the method I see Hibernate query

```
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_0_, product0_.created as created2_0_, product0_.description as descript3_0_, product0_.name as name4_0_, product0_.product_type_id as product_5_0_ from products product0_ order by product0_.id
```

and after some time I have OutOfMemoryError. 
The query hint didn't help.

How to read data using Spring Boot repository (or even EntityManager) and load rows from DB in optimal way. 
I know that I can make pagination, but as in articles was written, it is not the most optimal way.

Comment: What do you do with the stream? It is possible that you need to collect all the data from it? So the problem is related to that?

Comment: Post the code of the method using that stream.

Comment: In the post I shown the way how I use the stream.

Comment: It seems correct. So it depends on what you do in the export method. Or it depends on the implementation of the JpaRepository. Can you post the export method too?

Comment: I wrote in the post, export method has empty body. Does nothing. 
I am getting OutOfMemoryError because I read everything at once. How to read it part by part ?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment using spring all the data are retrieved and the Stream is applied only to data already in memory.

If you look at the source of `org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.PersistenceProvider` it seems that it uses a `ScrollableResults` to stream over the data.

Generally a `ScrollableResults` retrieve all data in memory.

You can find an interesting complete analysis using a MySql database [here](http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html), but probably the same works for a Postgres database.

So also if you think to use a solution that doesn't need to use a lot memory in reality it does because the underlying implementation is not using an optimal implementation.

Comment: Probably you didn't read my question carefully, because I added a link to the same article as you. The point of my question is that in this article it is written that I will not read all data to memory, but when I do it for PostgreSQL it reads all.

Answer (score 2):

You must detach the entity after your work finishes.

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
...
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
... 
// Your business logic
productRepository.streamAll().forEach(product -> {
   export(product);
   // must detach so that garbage collector can reclaim the memory.
   entityManager.detach(product);
});
```

Comment: Even though technically correct, this does not address the OP's issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same problem, and after long debugging of internals of spring data and hibernate have found solution which worked for me.

So to fetch data using the cursor in PostgreSQL it should be method with Stream result + annotation (kotlin syntax):

```
@QueryHints(QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.FETCH_SIZE, value = "50"))
```

which value it should be 50 or some else - it's not so important.
Probably you put the wrong name of the hint.

Comment: still does not work for me. By the way, Spring's HINT_FETCH_SIZE is an alias to Hibernate's FETCH_SIZE.